# Followup - Woocommerce different headers for each email types

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, header, email-notifications

**Objective**
Replace default email-header.php for some specific emails with custom email headers. I wish to **point to separate** email header template files.

I have
WordPress : 4.9.1
Woocommerce : 3.2.5

This is a question based on the solution provided here:
[Woocommerce different headers for each email types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27400044/woocommerce-different-headers-for-each-email-types)

I followed the code solution as provided by @helgatheviking here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27406663/8044005

Perhaps the solution provided earlier is not working due to changes in WP & WC

In my functions.php I have

```
    function so_27400044_remove_email_header(){
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_email_header', 'email_header');
}
add_action( 'init', 'so_27400044_remove_email_header' );
```

I created a new header file for this Admin New Order email and added the reference in my admin-new-order.php I have

```
<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_email_header', $email_heading, $email ); ?>
<?php wc_get_template( 'emails/admin-new-order-header.php', array( 'email_heading' => $email_heading ) ) ; ?>
```

When I test this email, I get both the headers! existing as well the new header I created!

Please guide me.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Woocommerce different headers for each email types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27400044/woocommerce-different-headers-for-each-email-types)

Comment: I have already mentioned the reference to the original thread and linked to it as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it's not possible to remove default email header for now in WooCommerce 3.2+, you should just remove from those specific email templates the following code line:

```
<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_email_header', $email_heading, $email ); ?>
```

Then just add instead (your custom template):

```
<?php wc_get_template( 'emails/admin-new-order-header.php', array( 'email_heading' => $email_heading ) ) ; ?>
```

I don't see for the moment another way.

Comment: Any otner way possible now ?

Comment: @melvin [Overriding woocommerce email templates via the active theme](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/) makes this possible, but this is something too broad to be asked in StackOverFlow and very specific to everyone.